# C/C++ compiler from command line

Tags: windows, c

I want to install GCC or another C/C++ compiler entirely from the command line in Windows. I've looked at Winget and and Chocolaty but I've only found GNU ARM products.

How do I install a C/C++ compiler entirely from the command line in Windows?

Comment: GCC requires WSL (Linux) or something like MinGW. You can use Chocolatey to install MinGW

Comment: https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/ https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?